# bash - The Best Elegant way to disable log file

Tags: linux, bash, sh, solaris, ksh

The following code is the basic concept of my log file in my bash script:

```bash
LOG=/tmp/BACKUP_PROCCESS.log
LOG_DISABLE=FALSE
MY_LOG ()
{
    [ $LOG_DISABLE = TRUE ] && return
    echo "[`date +%d"/"%b"/"%G"-"%T`] INFO $1" >> $LOG
}
MY_LOG "START TO BACKUP FILES UNDER /VAR/LOG"
```

This code helped me to understand or troubleshoot each step in my bash script, but sometimes I want to disable the log creation because we don't need them and I want to make the script more efficient (calling the log function on each line in the script takes time and makes the script more heavy).

So my question is:

What is the most elegant way to disable the log file?

Until now I've disabled the log function by returning inside it, but that solution was not great since I still call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have smart solution to disable the log file

example ,

```
   unset  -f  MY_LOG
   shopt -s expand_aliases
   alias MY_LOG=true
```

the command **unset** disable the **MY_LOG** function

and I add alias  **MY_LOG** to **true** command

the meaning of that is very time when **MY_LOG** will activate,  actually it will activate the **true** command , and **true** command not really do anything

Comment: Why not simply do `MY_LOG() { :; }` over those three lines?

Comment: If you ask me that's actually less elegant, especially if you're already using `aliases` which is a practice that's to be avoided when possible.

Answer (score 3):

Some would want to insert a condition checking everytime the logging function is called:

```
function log {
   if <not disabled>; then
       <show message>
   fi
}
```

And some like me would prefer removing any action to the function:

```
function log {
    :
}
```

This is what I do in my [logging function](https://sourceforge.net/p/playshell/code/ci/master/tree/source/log.sh).

Answer (score 1):

You could set your `$LOG` variable to `/dev/null`, which would cause the logs to go nowhere instead of into a file.

```
LOG_DISABLE=FALSE
if [[ $LOG_DISABLE = "TRUE" ]]; then
    LOG=/dev/null
fi
```

`/dev/null` is very fast so I wouldn't expect this to have any major performance disadvantages over your solution of returning from the function early.

Comment: Maybe you right -  But I still call the function , I search some other way/magic to disable the calling ( not sure if this possible ) , but I need to ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use some file descriptor redirections:

```
#!/bin/sh

log()
{
    echo >&3 $@
}

# Redirect all fd 3 in the file test.log
exec 3>$HOME/test.log

log this should be print

# Redirect all fd 3 in /dev/null
exec 3>/dev/null

log this sould not be print
```

and you will have in the file `test.log`

```
this should be print
```

Answer (score 0):

My way:

```
LOG_DISABLE="FALSE"
if [ $LOG_DISABLE = "TRUE" ]; then
   MY_LOG(){
      true
   }
else
   MY_LOG(){
      echo "[`date +%d"/"%b"/"%G"-"%T`] INFO $1" >> $LOG
   }
fi
```

Just defining the function differently based on the flag.
You will call the function either way but I hope true is a quick builtin ;)