# How do create an alias in shell scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, alias

Definin an alias on Linux system is very simple.

From the following example we see that: the `I_am_only_ls_alias` alias command gives us the output as `ls` command

```
 # alias I_am_only_ls_alias=ls
 # I_am_only_ls_alias
```

Output:

```
file   file1
```

But when I trying to do the same in bash script (`define alias I_am_only_ls_alias`), I get `I_am_only_ls_alias: command not found`.

Example of my bash script:

**`alias_test.bash`**

```
#!/bin/bash

alias I_am_only_ls_alias=ls

I_am_only_ls_alias
```

Run the bash script - `alias_test.bash`

```
/tmp/alias_test.bash
```

Output:

```
/tmp/: line 88: I_am_only_ls_alias: command not found
```

So, first I want to ask:

Why doesn't bash recognize the command `I_am_only_ls_alias` as an alias?

And what do I need to do in order to define aliases inside a bash script? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think aliases are inherited from a parent shell by a child shell.

Comment: @RSahu: not relevant here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the `bash` man page:

> Aliases  are  not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the `expand_aliases` shell option is set using `shopt` (see the
>          description of `shopt` under **SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS** below).

So this should work:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias I_am_only_ls_alias=ls
I_am_only_ls_alias
```

Scripts usually use functions, not aliases.

Comment: WELL DONE , this is what I want

Comment: well, you probably don't want to use aliases in scripts, NOBODY does.

Comment: Right. Aliases are usually short names for user convenience.

Comment: yes you right - but in some uniq case I need to define alias

Comment: I find that difficult to believe. Why doesn't it work if you define a function instead?

Comment: because in my bash script , I need to perform unalias , and as you know we cant disable function ( no way for unfunction ) -:)

Comment: From the man page: _A function definition may be deleted using the -f option to the unset builtin._

Comment: `unset -f I_am_only_ls_alias`

Comment: and How to enabled it back?

Comment: Define the function again. Now I'm really curious to see your script, to understand why you need to do this crazy thing.

Comment: Because I'll bet anything there's a better way to do what you're doing. This is most likely an XY problem.

Comment: Hi Barmar - see the reason for this quastion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008629/bash-the-best-elegant-way-to-disable-log-file/24057720#24057720

Answer (score 3):

Barmar's answer is the correct one for including an `alias`, but it's likely that you'll actually find a [Bash *function*](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) to be more flexible/useful.

For example this is materially the same as the `alias` version, but can be expanded much more easily:

```
timp@helez:~/tmp$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

function i_am_only_an_ls_func {
  ls "$@"
}

i_am_only_an_ls_func
timp@helez:~/tmp$ ./test.sh
0600871h.html
[snip]
timp@helez:~/tmp$
```

The `$@` is irrelavent in this example, but it means that anything after `i_am_only_an_ls_func` will be added after the `ls` command, since `$@`, `$1`, `$2`, etc contain the arguments to the function, much the same as for a normal script. (Note that `$0` is still the name of the *parent* script not the function)

Comment: Don't forget to quote around "$@"

Comment: @YzmirRamirez, yes that is a better way to do it, I've added them to the example.

Answer (score 1):

Aliases cannot be defined in shell script that you execute - their effect will be gone once shell process finished execution.

You can, however, define aliases in your `~/.bashrc` or in separate shell script that you `source` from (but not execute!). In that case, aliases are imported into already running shell process, and thus survive and actually work as you would expect.

Comment: He's trying to use the alias in the same script he defined it in.

Comment: @MVP I think Barmar have the solution